# Modify config/elasticsearch.yml after pip install elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, pip

I'm trying to install `elasticsearch` to work concurrently with `haystack` in my `django` project, and I installed it using

```
pip install elasticsearch
```

however, I need to make modifications to `config/elasticsearch.yml`.

Where do I find this file to edit after pip install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have downloaded **python client** for `elasticsearch`, You actually need to download [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch)

After that you can find the `config` file inside `$Your_ES_directory/config/elasticsearch.yml`